# How to create a post-service hook on a public github repository?

Tags: github, websub

I have no problem in creating hooks for my own repositories, however, I haven't found a way to create such hooks for a public repo.

Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're correct - it seems that it is not possible to subscribe to events of a repository you do not own (using PSHB), or create hooks for such repos.

Perhaps this would be a nice feature request to send to support@github.com.

Comment: I've emailed support@github.com and will update this with their response.