# Can I set a hook using API on public repo owned by someone else?

Tags: github, githooks, github-api

Is it possible to register an event hook on a public repository not owned by me using the github API? In other words, is there a way to listen to repo updates without asking the owner to add a hook linking to my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to subscribe to events of a repository you do not own (using PSHB), or create hooks for such repos. Something like this has been "requested" on SO before (e.g. here [How to create a post-service hook on a public github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319946/how-to-create-a-post-service-hook-on-a-public-github-repository/15967323)) so it may be a good idea to mention this to GitHub as a feature request (just send it to support@github.com).

Comment: thanks. I just did send them a request.

Comment: What is pshb? PubSubHubbub?